# How to find integral of the given function

Tags: calculus, integration

I have a question which asks us to solve the following integral:

[image]

My approach:

$(1+\sin(2x)^{1/2}=[(\sin x)^2+(\cos x)^2+(2\sin x)(\cos x)]^{1/2}=[((\sin x)+(\cos x))^2]^{1/2}$

What I did in the next step is that I took the equation to be (sinx)+(cosx) and then integrated it to get (-cosx)+(sinx).

If I plot the graph of my integral solution I get a continuous function,but I think it should be discontinuous function because when I checked my answer with Wolframalpha website it didn't match exactly and the answer was a discontinuous function.

Check the link for the answer given by the wolframalpha website:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(1%2Bsin(2x))%5E(1%2F2)

Since I don't have a pro account I couldn't access the step by step solution.

I don't understand how they ended up at this:

[image]

- Could you explain why the answer should be a discontinuous function?
- Why solving integral in my way isn't giving the exact answer?
- Is there any way or process that would give me exact answer?

I'm just looking for a better explanation and solution.

**Any little help is appreciated.**

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your way is that $$((\sin(x)+\cos(x))^2)^{1/2}=|\sin(x)+\cos(x)|\ne\sin(x)+\cos(x)$$

Hence when you integrate you left with $$\int|\sin(x)+\cos(x)|{dx}=\begin{cases}\int\sin(x)+\cos(x)dx=\sin(x)-\cos(x)+C&\sin(x)+\cos(x)\ge 0\\\int-(\sin(x)+\cos(x))dx=\cos(x)-\sin(x)+C&\mbox{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Which this is equivalent to what WolframAlpha gave at every point where both domains exists.